# The button resets after restarting the bot in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

After restarting the bot, the buttons do not work. I was looking for ways to fix it, but I didn't find it.

Code:

https://pastebin.com/yJwMhvF5

```
class TicketButton(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @nextcord.ui.button(label="Заявка", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def zayavka(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(EmbedModal())

@bot.command()
async def createticket(ctx):
    em = nextcord.Embed(color=nextcord.Color.blue())
    em.add_field(name="**Подача заявки**", value="Нажмите на кнопку ниже для открытия поля заполнения заявки", inline=False)
    em.add_field(name="", value="*Подать заявку снова будет невозможно!*", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=em, view=TicketButton())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. You'll need to make a view "persistent" for it to persist between restarts. You'll need to use [`bot.add_view`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.Client.add_view) to add the view for persistence. To do so, your view's `timeout` should be `None` (which it already is) and then your UI components will need to have [custom IDs](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.ui.Button.custom_id).

```py
class TicketButton(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @nextcord.ui.button(label="Заявка", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="my_custom_button")
    async def zayavka(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(EmbedModal())


# and then register the view for persistence
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.add_view(TicketButton())
```

Further reading:

- There's a [`discord.py` example here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py).
- There's also [pycord guide here](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/ui-components/buttons#persistent-views).

I know you're using `nextcord` but the libraries are still quite similar so these examples might be useful.

Comment: Happy to help! If this resolved your issue, this please mark this solution as the answer. Thanks!