# how to record button clicks by their custom_id | pycord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I need the bot to be able to record the button being pressed by its ID and for the bot to be able to send a message when the button is pressed after restarting.
an example of how it should work:

```
@bot.command
async def button(ctx):
    view=View(timeout=None)
    button=Button(label='Rules', style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id='rules')
    view.add_item(button)
    await ctx.send(view=view)

@bot.event()
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    if interaction.custom_id == 'rules':
        await interaction.message.send_channel('Server rules:', ephemeral=True)
```

I didn't find any similar functions in the documentation that work the way I need them to.

Comment: This isn't possible with events with the current py-cord version. See full event list [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/events.html#event-reference). Instead, try using regular callbacks to answer a button. If you want a button to be accessible after bot restart, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522323/the-button-resets-after-restarting-the-bot-in-discord-py)